# как открыть web приложение java через wildfly

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, wildfly

довольно стыдно это признавать, но не могу разобраться с wildfly.
Я создал простенькое web приложение на java, чтобы проверить как работает wildfly, 
но он открывает не страницу веб приложения, а начальную страницу настройки.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Простейшая настройка для IDEA:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конфигурация, например, порт находятся здесь: wildfly-16.0.0.Final\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]